# Shading under line with open left side in R

Tags: r, polygon

I am trying to shade the area above the zero-line in this graph:

This is the code with my attempt.

```
x <- c(seq(0.1, 0, length=50), seq(0,-0.2, length=50))
y <- c(0,seq(0.1,0, length=50),0)
plot(x, type = 'l')
abline(0,0)
polygon(x[1:52], y, col='skyblue')
```

However, when adding the `polygon` I get the following result:

What should I do to get the shaded area span from left to right (and not only as a vertical line)?

**Edit:** Apparently, since this is my first post I cannot upload pictures to the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: `polygon(1:52, y, col='skyblue')` . as you dont use an x-axis variable in your plot, you just need to use the index